# Function taking kwargs which are a dict whose keys are dynamically-generated strings

Tags: python, function, keyword-argument

Example:

```
def foo(v0 = 'a', v1 = 'b', v2 = 'c'):
    print(v0, v1, v2)

for i in range(0, 3):
    target = "v" + str(i)
    foo(target = 'z')
```

I wish the following output:

```
z b c
a z c
a b z
```

But, as it stands, the code above raises the following `TypeError`:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-7b3fb4086218> in <module>()
      4 for i in range(0, 3):
      5     target = "v" + str(i)
----> 6     foo(target = 'z')

TypeError: foo() got an unexpected keyword argument 'target'
```

How would I go about dynamically setting 'target' to 'v0', 'v1', etc.?

That's just an example of what I need to do. For my case, is to use along with SQLAlchemy to be able to dynamically choose the table that I will use. I can not use `if`.

Comment: why can't you use if?

Comment: `foo` has no keyword `target` . . .

Comment: @MattGiltaji For the reason that can reach any value, including newly created dynamically.

Comment: @dbliss I know that the above code does not work. It is only to describe what to do...

Comment: @KeplerBR I think dbliss was responding to Matt, not you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign keyword arguments to a function by unpacking the items of a dictionary with the `**` operator. Since dictionaries easily support strings as keys, it makes it very easy to assign to dynamic function parameters:

```
for i in range(0, 3):
    foo(**{'v{}'.format(i): 'z'})
```

Answer (score 8):

You should use a dict with keyword argument expansion (`**`):

```
for i in range(0, 3):
    target = "v" + str(i)
    kwarg = {target: 'z'}
    foo(**kwarg)
```

Or more simply:

```
for i in range(0, 3):
    foo(**{"v%s" % i: 'z'})
```